# Gaming mouse driver for Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, mouse, games, hardware

Just wondering if anyone had a good solution for this.

I got a Havitt Magic Eagle mouse off amazon and I was wondering if there was a way to get the proper drivers for it if the company doesnt provide any for linux.

Probably not right?

Anyway, just figured I'd ask, thanks ppl.

Mechsec

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone reverse-engineered the protocol of your specific mouse and put a driver on Github or somewhere else (use your favorite websearch) you are out of luck. For example I know there's a tool for Logitech G300 models.

Otherwise, if your mouse has certain keys or key combinations hardcoded into it, which is often the case, you could use something like xbindkeys to remap them to whatever you like.